# Why reporting duplicate key error after inserting data in SequoiaDB？

Tags: database, sequoiadb

When I insert data into SequoiaDB terminal using MySQL client, the terminal reports the error 49962 from storage engine, and the index key reports duplicate key error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Before SequoiaDB v3.0, the error code of MySQL is calculated as 49962 -50000, and it returns the error code -38.
2. Since you insert a duplicate value on the unique index key, so SequoiaDB returns -38 error to MySQL client.
3. The inserted duplicate key value can be located by checking the error log of the data master node.